# Eclipse: Step over shortcut only works after giving focus to the current editor window

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Whenever debugging code in Eclipse I run into this bug:

- Hit a breakpoint
- Step into another class using the keyboard shortcut
- Hit Step Over using the keyboard shortcut

The third step never steps over unless I first focus the editor window on the current Java file.

How can I overcome having to use the mouse to focus the editor window every time I step into a separate class?

My environments are as follows (the bug has been on multiple operating systems):

OS: OS X 10.8.2 and Windows 7

Base Eclipse with Android Developer Tools installed separately.

Java 6

Comment: Can you provide more info, such as what OS you are using, what version of Eclipse are you using, and what plugins you have installed (if any?)

Comment: Yep, we need this information.  I do what you describe ALL THE TIME, with no problems, obviously that is the way it is supposed to work.  So there must be something different about your environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that the debug shortcuts are applied to In Windows rather than Debugging.

- Open Preferences
- General > Keys
- Type filter text of "step "
- Change Step Into, Step Over and Step Out to "In Windows" instead of "Debugging" in the When dropdown.

Comment: Step Into (F5) collides with Refresh (F5) command that has the same when condition (In Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me, but I hate overriding F5 for REFRESH in most windows.

The better solution would be for Eclipse to correctly detect when I'm debugging.